# Showing the tab on button click

Tags: 2010, development, ribbon

Basically my questiong is regarding the ribbon.

So I want to have the following behaviour, when a person clicks on the button, the contextual ribbon tab should be opened.

Any idea how to do that?

I have the following code:

```
            SPRibbon ribbon = SPRibbon.GetCurrent(this.Page);
            string contextualTabId = ribbonItems[listType];         
            ribbon.MakeTabAvailable(contextualTabId);
            ribbon.MakeContextualGroupInitiallyVisible(contextualTabId, string.Empty);
```

But the problem is it disappeares after a second.

Another solution might be to focus the web part but how to do it from c#? I tried with js but was not a good solution. And it didn't work very well either.

So any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically I've still succeeded to fix my problem by using the JavaScript.

Here is the code:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ2");
if (elem != null) {
    var dummyevent = new Array();
    dummyevent["target"] = elem;
    dummyevent["srcElement"] = elem;
    elem.parentNode.click(); 
    WpClick(dummyevent);
   }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I had to add something to make it work:

Answer (score 2):

I had to add window.onload to make Shkipper's answer work:

```
<script unselectable="on">
  window.onload = function(){
  var elem = document.getElementById("MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ2");
  if (elem != null) {
      var dummyevent = new Array();
      dummyevent["target"] = elem;
      dummyevent["srcElement"] = elem;
      elem.parentNode.click(); 
      WpClick(dummyevent);
// Below code will click browse

document.getElementsByClassName("ms-cui-tt-span")[0].click();
   }
}
</script>
```

Comment: This will default open the respective ribbon. added `document.getElementsByClassName("ms-cui-tt-span")[0].click();` in code to stop this behavior.